# Specifying that function argument is positive

Tags: function-construction, expression-test

Struggling with something basic. Suppose when defining f[x_] the outcome depends on Sign[x].  When calling this function, how do I tell Mathematica the sign of the argument?
My attempt:

```
f[x_]=x Sign[x];
Assuming[a>0, f[a]]
```

The output I get is

```
a Sign[a]
```

Obviously, I want to get simply `a` because I am trying to tell Mathematica `a` is positive

**Additional details:**

Thanks for the answers below. What I am really trying to do is as follows:

```
p = x /. Solve[(a - x)/y^2 == 1, x];
q = ((3 a - 2 p)/(4 y^2));
f[x_] = x Sign[x] ;
Assuming[q > 0, Simplify[f[q]]]
```

If I delete the first line in which `p` is defined via Solve, everything works fine. If, however, the first line is present, the output is:

```
{((a + 2 y^2) Sign[a + 2 y^2])/(4 y^2 Sign[y]^2)}
```

So, the Sign operator is still there.

What's wrong?

Comment: From the documentation for [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html): "Assuming[assum, expr] evaluates expr with assum appended to $Assumptions, so that assum is included in the default assumptions used by functions such as Refine, Simplify, and Integrate." That is, the assumptions are only used by functions that take the option `Assumptions`. Your function `f` does not, so the assumption has no affect. `Simplify[f[a], a > 0]`

Comment: Thanks! I'd be grateful if you checked the update in the initial post

Comment: Try using `FullSimplify` instead of `Simplify`. `FullSimplify` works a little harder to reduce things as much as possible.

Comment: Sjoerd, this does not help - FullSimplify simply replaces Sign with Abs operator.

Comment: Using `$Assumptions={q>0};` right at the beginning does the job. Then instead of `Assuming[q > 0, Simplify[f[q]]]` use `Simplify[f[q]]`.

Comment: `x Sign[x]` is just `Abs[x]`, why not use the simpler expression?

Comment: If you do not like the idea of @J.M. or if you have a more complex function, you might like to define the function using `Simplify` just in its definition. For example, `f[x_]:=Simplify[someExpression[x], x>0]`. In your case it would be `f[x_]:=Simplify[x*Sign[x], x>0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

p = x /. Solve[(a - x)/y^2 == 1, x];

q = ((3 a - 2 p)/(4 y^2));

f[x_] = x Sign[x];

Assuming[q > 0, FullSimplify[f[q]]]

(* {Abs[a + 2 y^2]/(4 y^2)} *)
```

Note the presence of [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) brackets that originate in your definition of `p`

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to remove the `List` brackets in the definition of `p`

```
p = x /. Solve[(a - x)/y^2 == 1, x][[1]];

q = ((3 a - 2 p)/(4 y^2));

f[x_] = x Sign[x];

Assuming[q > 0, Simplify[f[q]]]

(* 1/4 (2 + a/y^2) *)
```

**EDIT:** For the more complicated expression in your comment,

```
p = x /. Solve[(a - x)/(c y^2) + (b - x)/(d y^2) == 1, x][[1]];

q = ((3 a - 2 p)/(4 y^2))

(* (3 a - (2 (b c + a d - c d y^2))/(c + d))/(4 y^2) *)

f[x_] = x Sign[x];
```

If all the variables are real,

```
sol = Assuming[
  q > 0, (f[q] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &)]

(* Sqrt[(3 a - (2 (b c + a d - c d y^2))/(c + d))^2]/(4 y^2) *)
```

This avoids `Abs` but is not the simplest form. Since the numerator is `Sqrt[q^2]` and `q > 0`

```
sol /. Sqrt[(z_)^2] :> z // Simplify

(* (3 a c - 2 b c + a d + 2 c d y^2)/(4 (c + d) y^2) *)
```

Comment: Hi Bob,thanks your solution works, but if I try to add another term to the first equation, so that the equation being solved is `(a - x)/(c y^2) + (b - x)/(d y^2) == 1`, and everything else is the same - including your new thing `[[1]]`, then again sign operator appears in the outcome!

Comment: Following up on my previous comment: if parameters `c` and `d` are removed from the denominators, there is no "Sign" in the answer. With `c` and `d` however, Sign pops up again

Comment: @DmitryMakarov - If all the variables are real, 

`Assuming[q > 0, f[q] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &]`.

Comment: Bob, this works, thanks! If I may ask, what was the obstacle that FullSimplify cannot overcome, but CompexExpand can? Is ComplexExpand the universally better approach to the broad question of Evaluating functions with a positive argument? Or if I keep increasing the complexity of the equation being solved, ComplexExpand will at some point also stop working, and then you'll recommend me another solution? If possible, I'd like as a takeaway to learn the most universal approach to this question. Thanks again!

Comment: There is no universal approach since you are trying to avoid a particular form (`Abs[ ]`) that Mathematica finds perfectly acceptable. As general rules: include all available info about constraints in assumptions; and, if you want to specify particular forms (`{RE, Im}`, `{Abs, Arg}`, or `Conjugate`), you will probably need `ComplexExpand`. When using `ComplexExpand` either all variables must be real or you must explicitly identify which are complex. Some experimentation will often be required. See the `See Also` section of the documentation for `Simplify` for functions that may be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bob!

Comment: Most of all, I try to understand how Mathematica "thinks", because it will help to deal with various types of problems. Currently, I learned some approaches from you, but it still remains a mystery why Mathematica understands perfectly well when I write  "Assuming q>0" and the first equation has one term, it also understands this when there are two terms without `c` and `d` in the denominators, but then suddenly ComplexExpand is needed once I put  `c` and `d`. Something interesting going on under the hood, maybe I'll figure out one day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_]=x Sign[x];
Assuming[a>0,FunctionExpand[f[a]]]
```

returns a

```
Assuming[a>0,Simplify[f[a]]]
```

returns a

Comment: Thanks! I'd be grateful if you checked the update in the initial post